# Angular 7: ngModel data binding does not update component property in unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an Angular 7 component with the property `searchTerm` and an input-element in its template. The value of the property is bound to the value of the input-element via `[(ngModel)]="searchTerm"`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  template: `
    <form class="search-form">
      <mat-form-field class="search-form-field">
        <input matInput
               type="text"
               id="search-input"
               [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
               name="search-input">
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent {
  searchTerm: string;
}
```

In my unit tests, I try to test if the property changes to the value of the input-element:

```js
it('should update searchTerm according to the input-value', async (() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const input = fixture.debugElement
                  .query(By.css('#search-input')).nativeElement;
    input.value = 'test-value';
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() =>
      expect(component.searchTerm).toEqual('test-value')
    );
  }));
```

However, all I get is the following error message:

> Expected undefined to equal 'test-value'.

Interestingly though, the binding fully works when I manually try it in a browser. Also, I already tried to use `fakeAsync` instead of `async` in my test function but it did not make any difference.

What am I doing wrong?